# How to Generate a Specific Tabular Output from Two SQL Tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, "position" and "employee," and I need to generate a specific tabular output that combines data from both tables. The expected output should display positions and employees in a specific format:

Schema :

```
drop table if exists job_positions;
create table job_positions
(
    id          int,
    title       varchar(100),
    groups      varchar(10),
    levels      varchar(10),
    payscale    int,
    totalpost   int
);
insert into job_positions values (1, 'General manager', 'A', 'l-15', 10000, 1);
insert into job_positions values (2, 'Manager', 'B', 'l-14', 9000, 5);
insert into job_positions values (3, 'Asst. Manager', 'C', 'l-13', 8000, 10);

drop table if exists job_employees;
create table job_employees
(
    id              int,
    name            varchar(100),
    position_id     int
);
insert into job_employees values (1, 'John Smith', 1);
insert into job_employees values (2, 'Jane Doe', 2);
insert into job_employees values (3, 'Michael Brown', 2);
insert into job_employees values (4, 'Emily Johnson', 2);
insert into job_employees values (5, 'William Lee', 3);
insert into job_employees values (6, 'Jessica Clark', 3);
insert into job_employees values (7, 'Christopher Harris', 3);
insert into job_employees values (8, 'Olivia Wilson', 3);
insert into job_employees values (9, 'Daniel Martinez', 3);
insert into job_employees values (10, 'Sophia Miller', 3);

select * from job_positions;
select * from job_employees;
```

output :

[image]

Here Is what I have tried so far but did not get the expected result

```
WITH RankedEmployees AS (
    SELECT
        p.TITLE AS TITLE,
        p.GROUPS AS "GROUP",
        p.LEVELS AS LEVEL,
        p.PAYSCALE AS PAYSCALE,
        e.NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY e.ID) AS emp_rank
    FROM position p
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON p.ID = e.POSITION_ID
)
SELECT
    TITLE,
    "GROUP",
    LEVEL,
    PAYSCALE,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN emp_rank = 1 THEN EMPLOYEE_NAME END), 'Vacant') AS EMPLOYEE_NAME
FROM RankedEmployees
GROUP BY TITLE, "GROUP", LEVEL, PAYSCALE
ORDER BY TITLE, "GROUP", LEVEL, PAYSCALE;
```

Comment: 1) In your INSERT statements you have level values like 'l-15' but in your output these appear to be dates - can you explain this, please? 2) Your table creation scripts don't match your SQL query e.g. the table names - can you ensure that all the information you provide is consistent, please? 3) Please can you explain the logic for generating the rows that have the employee name as 'Vacant' - and why do you have multiple identical rows where the employee name is "Vacant"?

Comment: yes, the table schemas are not sound in the first place.

Comment: i have coorected it

Comment: @Sam no you haven’t, and you haven’t explained the logic either

Answer (score 0):

There's issues with your tables.

We can't expect vacancies in the results of a query if every ID available in job_positions table has been assigned to an employee in the job_employees table.